# Import csv data as array in mongodb using mongoimport

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have been trying to import the csv data into mongodb using mongoimport. The collection is like this:

```
{
id:"122234343",
name: "name1",
children: ["222334444","333344444"]
}
```

One approach I tried is to create 2 csv files - one with id & name and other with id, children (if id has two children then it will have two rows). Import the data into two different collections using mongoimport and then use update the collection data using foreach() at second collection having children data.

Please suggest is there any another way to populate this "children" array directly from CSV??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To me, the simplest way to work out how to format your "CSV" for [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) is to simply create a collection then use [`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) on it to see what the CSV format should look like.

So create your document from the shell:

```
db.newcol.insert({
  id:"122234343",
  name: "name1",
  children: ["222334444","333344444"]
})
```

Then exit the shell and run `mongoexport`:

```
 mongoexport -d test -c testcol --fields id,name,children --type csv > out.csv
```

Which will show you the output as:

```
id,name,children
122234343,name1,"[""222334444"",""333344444""]"
```

Where the "array" is represented with a "string" and using the quotes `""` in their escaped form.

That now is a pretty clear place to use `mongoimport` from, so just "import" now to test:

```
mongoimport -d test -c newcol --headerline --type csv out.csv
```

Re-enter the shell and see the document(s) in the new collection:

```
db.newcol.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59476924d6eb0b7d6ac37e02"),
        "id" : 122234343,
        "name" : "name1",
        "children" : "[\"222334444\",\"333344444\"]"
}
```

So everything is there, **BUT** the children are listed as a "string" rather than an array. But this is not really a problem, since we got the data imported and now it's just up us to now actually transform it:

```
var ops = [];
db.testcol.find({ "children": { "$type": 2} }).forEach(doc => {
  var children = doc.children.split(',').map( e => e.replace(/"|\[|\]|\\/gm,'').toString() );
  ops.push({
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
      "update": { "$set": { "children": children } }
    }
  });

  if ( ops.length >= 1000 ) {
    db.newcol.bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }             
});

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
  db.newcol.bulkWrite(ops);
  ops = [];
}
```

So that is going to iterate anything that was imported into the collection that has a BSON type of 2 which is "string" via the [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) query operator.

Then we take the string, split it as an array and strip the other characters to only leave the value you want.

Using [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) you commit those updates in an efficient way, rather than writing every single document per request. They are actually sent in batches of 1000 to the server.

The end result is the document in the original wanted form:

```
db.testcol.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5947652ccb237bd6e4e902a5"),
        "id" : "122234343",
        "name" : "name1",
        "children" : [
                "222334444",
                "333344444"
        ]
}
```

So that is my "step by step" of how you can work out your CSV format, import it and then "transform" the data into the state that you need it.

Comment: Probably the best answer on the subject across the internet.

Comment: do you have a solution using MongoDB compass?

Answer (score 0):

The more simpler way is to format your csv file

In accordance with your example the column names should look like this

**id   name   children.0   children.1**

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, and in addition to the accepted answer, if you have `embedded documents`, just import csv and use `JSON.parse` for the property having embedded data and update original document as in below code sample:

```
db.myCollectionName.find({ }).forEach(doc => {   
    // parse the embedded document
    var myPropertyValue = JSON.parse(doc.myPropertyName);   
    // update the original document, or push to a new collection, etc
    db.myCollectionName.updateOne({"_id": doc._id}, [ {$set:{ "myPropertyName" : myPropertyValue}}]);     
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**collection is like below:**

```
   {
       "_id" : ObjectId("580100f4da893943d393e909"),
       "username" : "crystal",
       "likes" : [ "running", "pandas", "software development" ]
    }
```

**below command for csv to mongodb:**

```
mongoimport --db users --type csv --headerline --file /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

actually Mongodb is non relational db so no need of creating two csv to import

Comment: Thanks Vishal but what format should we use to keep this "likes" data in CSV??

Comment: you can keep any type of data based on your requirement